# Else after return from first part of an if statement

Tags: java, performance, if-statement, return, readability

The implementation of library's `BigInteger.gcd(...)` method begins with these statements:

```
public BigInteger gcd(BigInteger val) {
    if (val.signum == 0)
        return this.abs();
    else if (this.signum == 0)
        return val.abs();
    ...
}
```

What is the purpose of the `else` keyword in this case? Is it just a remnant of an old code that the programmer has forgotten to delete or it impacts performance in some way?

I understand that, semantically, the versions with and without `else` are identical in this particular case. Quite often, however, I face the choice between

```
<Some method signature>(...) {
    if (...) {
        <Short branch>
        return ...;
    } else {
        <Long branch>
        return ...;
    }
}
```

and

```
<Some method signature>(...) {
    if (...) {
        <Short branch>
        return ...;
    }
    <Long branch>
    return ...;
}
```

Which option is better in terms of performance (note that this question is Java-specific)? If performance is almost identical in both cases, which one is better in terms of readability?

Comment: The library implementation is not using braces `{}`, so I don't know how much credence I would give to their particular style. I also don't know the age of the given code. Nor do I know of any performance difference (and the JIT is likely to have optimizations for both cases). As for readability, that is subjective opinion. But I think the short branch in the `if` and then no `else` is most readable. You might also decompose "long branch" to delegate to different methods. But that's literally just my own opinion.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch This code is from JDK 8 and JDK 11 (the given part is the same), the copyright line at the top refers to *1996, 2018*. With regard to braces `{}`, they use them few lines above. My personal opinion is that they aren't needed for one-line blocks, but I think that this is irrelevant here.

Comment: I think you can be absolutely sure that such trivial differences in usage of `if`/`else` are covered by JIT optimizations. In terms of readability: I'd go with the third code snippet for short methods and with the second snippet for long ones.

Comment: It’s a matter of style and taste. I could have found it natural to write the code in the way seen in `gcd()`, only I would have included braces.

Comment: For what it’s worth, Eclipse has a setting to flag or even forbid *Unnecessary 'else' statement*, for programmers or teams who don’t like the way it’s done in `gcd()`. It’s under Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings->Unnecessary code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my machine, using java 1.8.0_172, the two versions produce identical bytecode. So this is optimized at compile-time itself. The JIT compiler would see the same input in both cases, so the runtime performance will be identical.

Else version:

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 2) {
                System.out.println("More than 2");
                return;
        } else {
                System.out.println("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

No-else version:

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 2) {
                System.out.println("More than 2");
                return;
        }
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Then compile them with `java MyTest.java`, and then get the bytecode with `javap -c MyTest`, compare the bytecode from the two sources. They are identical. Both generate the following bytecode:

```
Compiled from "MyTest.java"
public class MyTest {
  public MyTest();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: arraylength
       2: iconst_2
       3: if_icmple     15
       6: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       9: ldc           #3                  // String More than 2
      11: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      14: return
      15: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
      18: ldc           #5                  // String Hello
      20: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
      23: return
}
```

Now for readability, that is subjective of course. I prefer the version without the unnecessary `else`.

Answer (score 2):

My $0.02 worth: when faced with a choice of either

```
<Some method signature>(...) {
    if (...) {
        <Short branch>
        return ...;
    } else {
        <Long branch>
        return ...;
    }
}
```

or

```
<Some method signature>(...) {
    if (...) {
        <Short branch>
        return ...;
    }
    <Long branch>
    return ...;
}
```

I like to go with option #3 whenever possible:

```
<Some method signature>(...) {
    T result;        
    if (...) {
        <Short branch>
        result = ...;
    } else {
        <Long branch>
        result = ...;
    }
    return result;
```

For a simple case like this, I like having the single logical end of the method (i.e., the `return` statement) which coincides with its physical end.

More efficient? 
Doubtful.

*Less* efficient? Probably not.

More readable? *I* think so, but I can neither guarantee *you'll* think so, nor prove that you should.

Just throwing it out there.

Comment: Thanks for the third version. I prefer to create local variables only when this is unavoidable, that's why I missed such a possibility here. In theory, having several return points instead of a single one shouldn't affect performance.